# Where in pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, where-clause

I have next pivot table:

```
Schema::create('coach_user', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('coach_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('coach_id')->references('id')->on('coaches')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->tinyInteger('rank');
        });
```

In User.php:

```
 public function coaches()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Coach::class)->withPivot('rank');
    }
```

How I can receive coaches of user with some rank? Something like this:

```
$user->coaches->where('rank',1)->get().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [wherePivot()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to `filter` the results returned by `belongsToMany`.

```
$user->coaches()->wherePivot('rank',1)->get();
```

Comment: Don't work. But work next: $user->coaches()->wherePivot('rank',1)->get(). Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Use `wherePivot` for pivot columns and relation as method:

```
$user->coaches()->wherePivot('rank',1)->get().
```